# Which environment variables the app is using

Tags: c, unix, environment-variables, getenv

I have binary executable file compiled from C-source and I know that it uses some of UNIX system environment variables. Unfortunately I have no documentation and decompiling/reverse-engineering is very difficult.

Is there a way to find which env variables the app tries to read in runtime?

I mean, if C's `getenv` reads some file to get variable values or does a system call, it is possible. So, can I do it?

Comment: I'm not an expert on the environment variables, but I think you can trace system calls with `ptrace`.

Comment: `strings(1)` might help you to identify the names of the envrionment variables.

Comment: @Benno Zeeman: `strace` (this is what you meant probably, `ptrace()` is the system call `strace` utilizes) won't help much here. `getenv()` is not a system call, it's a C library function that basically just dereferences the third parameter of the `main()` function (available as `__environ` pointer to every C program) which points to the process memory area where environment variables are stored.

Comment: mfro, thank you for this info. I checked getenv implementation and indeed it does not do anything except reading `__environ`.

Comment: As a supporting answer to @BennoZeeman's answer . You can also use the `ltrace` tool to check the calls for `getenv`.

Answer (score 1):

`strings(1)` might help you to identify the names of the envrionment variables.
                    – Blagovest Buyukliev

Answer (score 1):

One can use a debugger, set a breakpoint on `getenv`, and inspect the function argument. This is possible even without debug information (albeit more difficult, since it requires knowledge of the calling convention).